# copy a hotfix from master to branch on sourcetree

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging, atlassian-sourcetree

I have made a quick-fix on master. I'd like to copy that small fix to some other branches. 
I tried to push it to another branch by selecting the master>selecting the commit>push>check some branch>ok. but when I click over to the branch there are no changes to be pulled.

After digging around I see this would have been easily accomplished with git-flow but now is too late and would require a whole other thread to figure out how to set up git-flow because my branch structure is different.

What is the simplest way now to push the change I made to another branch?

I guess i can always just physically copy\paste the changes but what is the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't merge, I would recommend cherry-pick.  Here's how to do it in SourceTree:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/308089/how-to-use-cherry-pick-in-sourcetree

And here's an explanation of cherry-pick:

http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html